# PHP - null coalescing operator

Tags: php, operators

In my Symfony project I wrote  a method where I need to check to tables in db.

I am looking for an id parameter that I passed in my API call. It has to be the same as for logged in user which is defined $this->getUser().

I have *$account* and *$paymentDevice* of which $account->getUser() is returning null as that entity does not exist in db. It exists in $paymentDevice->getUser() but it's like **||** **(OR)** does not get to the second value. I tried with **?:** , **??** but non of the work. 
When I replace the order it works.

How to fix that?

```
public function clearSomething($id)
 {
        $type = $this->getTypeRepository()->findOneBy([
            'id' => $id
        ]);

    $account = $this->getAccountRepository()->find($id);
    $paymentDevice= $this->getPaymentDeviceRepository()->find($id);

    if ($account->getUser() === $this->getUser() || $paymentDevice->getUser() ===  $this->getUser()) {
        $this->em->remove($type);
        $this->em->flush();
    } else { throw new \Exception('Type does not belong to this Account/PaymentDevice!'); }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it like this too?

```
$account = $this->getAccountRepository()->find($id);
$paymentDevice= $this->getPaymentDeviceRepository()->find($id);

$service = $account ?? $paymentDevice;
if ($service !== null && $service->getUser() === $this->getUser()) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. Yes I did. It says:  Call to a member function getUser() on null.  @MihaiMatei

Comment: So the `$account` variable could be actually null too right?

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working as it should. @MihaiMatei